# Count how many rows that have a special value in a column

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

I'm trying to count how many rows that have the same value as a variable.

Then I wanna echo out the number that is calculated in the mysql query!
Is this possible?

Here is a image of my database:

http://img812.imageshack.us/img812/333/9jr1.png

Sorry for my bad English and if the question is hard to understand (new to this stuff)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is from your old question

```
$query= "SELECT pic_name, count(pic_name) as count FROM hulebild_likes where pic_name='$bild_id'";

$likesf = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($likesf);
echo $row['count'];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two different approaches here. If you're looking for a *specific* value and know it in advance, you can do something as simple as:

```
select count(*) as count from table where column = 'value';
```

Alternatively, if you're just looking for a count of duplicate values, you could go with something like:

```
select count(*) as count, column from table group by column;
```

That will give you two columns: your column of values and how many occurrences there are of each value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How do I echo this out after that?

Answer (score 0):

Execute a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtablename WHERE yourcolumnname = yourvariablevalue;
```